# How to retrieve references of views which are defined programatically

Tags: android, android-view, android-tablelayout

Ideally One can retrieve a View reference(in an xml file) through findViewById method.
However i have a class where i have instantiated all views

```
    public View Initialise(Context context){

    private Button mBoardButtons[][] = new Button[gridSize][gridSize];
       private TableRow rowArr[] = new TableRow[gridSize];
        private TextView mInfoTextView;
        private TextView mPlayer;
        private TextView mPlayerCount;
     TableLayout tableLayout1 = new TableLayout(context);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams1 = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tableParams1.topMargin = 0;
        tableLayout1.setLayoutParams(tableParams1);

        for ( int i =0 ; i < gridSize ; i++){
            rowArr[i] = new TableRow(context);
            TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rowParams.gravity=Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
            rowArr[i].setLayoutParams(rowParams);
            for(int j = 0; j < gridSize ; j++){
                mBoardButtons[i][j] = new Button(context);
                mBoardButtons[i][j].setText(Integer.toString(i)+","+Integer.toString(j));
                mBoardButtons[i][j].setTextSize(150/gridSize);
                mBoardButtons[i][j].setMaxHeight(450/gridSize);
                mBoardButtons[i][j].setMaxWidth(600/gridSize);
                rowArr[i].addView(mBoardButtons[i][j]);

            }
            tableLayout1.addView(rowArr[i]);
        }


        mInfoTextView = new TextView(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.topMargin = 5;
            params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
        mInfoTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
        mInfoTextView.setText("Info");
        mInfoTextView.setTextSize(25);
        tableLayout1.addView(mInfoTextView);


        TableLayout tableLayout2 = new TableLayout(context);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams2 = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tableLayout2.setLayoutParams(tableParams2);

        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(context);

        mPlayer = new TextView(context);

        mPlayer.setText("Player: ");
        tableRow.addView(mPlayer);

        mPlayerCount = new TextView(context);

        mPlayerCount.setText(" ");

        tableRow.addView(mPlayerCount);


    return tableLayout1;

}
```

The above code was defined in a particular class(Lets say its a substitute for an xml file)

Now how do i get retrieve references for all these View elements in my Activity class.

Is there any method similar to method to findViewById for retrieving programatically defined view references?

Comment: Why don't you keep references in the same class as members so that you could just add some getters and access to these views in your activity class

Answer (score 0):

When you create them with new you have the reference.  Save it somewhere.

Or you can use setID() so you can use findViewByID later.  But its silly to do that when you can just save it now.

Comment: In xml files we inflate or do a setContentView(R.layout.xmlfile)

How do i the same for being able to reference programatically defined View elements?

Comment: IF you're creating them programatically, then you have the references when you create them.  Just save them for later use.  Or you can call setID on each one and later use findViewByID on that id.